# Why does the view disappear after fade-in completes in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I want an element to fade in and stay there but using general code available on the internet, animation works fine but it disappears the element after completion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:fillAfter="true" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
 <alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
</set>
```

and Android code is

```
       AnimationSet mAnimationSet = new AnimationSet(false); //false means don't share interpolators
       Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.simple_fade_in);
       mAnimationSet.addAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
       v.startAnimation(mAnimationSet);
```

Comment: Hey, this code is correct and it doesn't disappear, cause you set alpha from 0 to 1, I've tested and it works as we expected, let me know if there is something else.

Comment: @YousefKazemi It's disappearing in my application. I think I have to check some other things that may be the actual reason for this.

Comment: Yeah maybe, I'd recommend testing just this animation separately, then If it's ok, then check other things.